# Append an element from list1 to list2 randomly then delete this element from list1 at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x

for example:

```
Cards = 13       
    while Cards > 0:
        card1 = ["FLOUR", "MONKEY", "DOLLAR", "LOVE", "POISON"]
        print ("Aktive Player: enter a number between 1 and 5 to choose the Mystry word")
    
        Mystry = []
        x = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
        while True:
            response = input('>')
            if response not in x:
                print ("Aktive Player: enter a number between 1 and 5 to choose the Mystry word")
            else:
                Mystry = random.choice(card1)
                break

print(Mystry)
print(card1)
```

if Mystry = "FLOUR" , how to delete "FLOUR" from card1 so it would not come in the next loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an index of your last choice with index() method than remove it with pop(ind) with the argument of the found index. Example below

```
Cards = 13       
    while Cards > 0:
        card1 = ["FLOUR", "MONKEY", "DOLLAR", "LOVE", "POISON"]
        print ("Aktive Player: enter a number between 1 and 5 to choose the Mystry word")
    
        Mystry = []
        x = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
        while True:
            response = input('>')
            if response not in x:
                print ("Aktive Player: enter a number between 1 and 5 to choose the Mystry word")
            else:
                Mystry = random.choice(card1)
                ind = card1.index(Mystry)
                card1.pop(ind)
                break

print(Mystry)
print(card1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's `list.pop()` method - from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

list.pop([i])

```
Remove the item at the given position in the list, and return it.
If no index is specified, a.pop() removes and returns the last item in the list. 
(The square brackets round the i in the method signature denote that the parameter is optional,
not that you should type square brackets at that position.
You will see this notation frequently in the Python Library Reference.)
```

Basically your code where you add the item to `Mystery` should look like this:

```
Mystery = card1.pop(random.choice(range(0, len(card1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just shuffle the list, assign the first item to `Mystry` and the rest back to `card1`

```
random.shuffle(card1)
Mystry, *card1 = card1
```